# Como ter um resultado misturando checkbox'es?

Tags: c#, wpf

Como eu posso combinar resultados de `checkbox`?

Com 5 `checkbox`, por exemplo, como eu faço o resultado ser combinado para quando o usuário selecionar a 5 e a 3 aparece uma messenger box.

Ps: Se a pergunta estiver vaga avisar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta fazer isso:

```
if(meuCheckBox3.Checked && meuCheckBox5.Checked)
{
    //Combinação 1
}
if (meuCheckBox1.Checked && meuCheckBox4.Checked)
{
    //Combinação 2
}
if (meuCheckBox1.Checked && meuCheckBox2.Checked && meuCheckBox3.Checked)
{
    //Combinação 3
}
```

Você pode fazer isso dentro de um método e chamar esse método nos eventos de click dos `checkbox`.